# Inserting image in pug template engine

Tags: pug

I am working with PUG template engine,Unable to insert image. I have my image stored in current folder where this file is stored. Any help would be appreciated.
Unable to load image. Following is the code written for image.

```
img(src='./login_icon', alt='login', style='width:100px;height:100px;')
```

Comment: What specific error did you get? It's not clear whether your "Unable" sentences are quotes or just you vaguely saying it didn't work. Please, clarify the question.

Comment: Hi,I mean the image is not coming on the page.I am getting the alternate text for the image

Answer (score 5):

It should be:

```
img(src='./login_icon' alt='login' style='width:100px; height:100px;')
```

Simply remove the comma.

Comment: Did this end up working? I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on node.js.
move to your server.js and add this code.

```
app.use('/pictures', express.static(process.cwd() + '/pictures'));
```

where pictures is the picture folder

```
img(src='./Pictures/pic1')
```

this in your .pub file

Answer (score 0):

What I can see in your example is that it doesn't have the image extension.

```
img(src='./login_icon.svg' alt='login' style='width:100px;height:100px;')
```

Check that and also the path of it.